# How do I embed artifact information in maven shaded jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I would like to document in the shaded jar what maven artifacts actually end up in that shaded jar.

All the packages get merged and that makes it difficult to workout exactly what artifacts went into it just by looking at the jar.

I suppose the ideal place for that information would be the manifest file but it could just be in a text file.

Ideally I want to see groupId, artifactId and version.

Is this at all possible with the maven shade plugin?

Thanks in advance, Phil.

Comment: It's unlikely you can get this kind of information from anything other than the shade plugin itself. So I would look into its [configuration properties](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html). For example there's option `createDependencyReducedPom` which can be combined with `keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope` to get a modified pom.xml with included dependencies marked with `provided` scope. I don't see a way to differentiate them from originally `provided` dependencies, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with maven, below steps to follow:

1- Create under ***src/main/resources*** a file wich will contain the information, information.txt for example with the following content:

```
version=${project.version}
artifactId=${project.artifactId}
groupId=${project.groupId}
```

2- **Activate Maven filtring**

```
 <project>
      ...
      <build>
        ...
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/information.txt</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
          ...
        </resources>
        ...
      </build>
      ...
    </project>
```

3- Build your project. The file will contain now the information you need.

[More information about the plugin.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: This allows to print any property to a text file and include it in the final jar. But this doesn't explain how to find out which artifacts became part of the shaded jar, when shade plugin could be configured in many different ways to include only some artifacts or even relocate stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As it doesn't like this is supported by the shade plugin i have requested this feature.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-236

Answer (score 0):

When building jars with Maven, by default you will get the following entries: `/META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.properties` and `/META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.xml`. When shading, all these files will also end up in the shaded jar.